# Looking for access to McKean's original paper?

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, parabolic-pde, paper-request

I'm looking for the PDF version/scan of Henry P McKean Jr.'s paper on propagation of chaos. The reference is as follows -

**Propagation of chaos for a class of non-linear parabolic equations., In Stochastic Differential Equations (Lecture Series in Differential Equations, Session 7, Catholic Univ., 1967) (1967): 41-57.**

The paper/chapter has been cited numerous times (being one of the first papers in the field) but nowhere online can I find a pdf version of it. It seems to me that most people who cite it haven't actually seen/read it.

Comment: Did you try going to the library? Ours (otherwise unremarkable) collection has a copy, so surely they must have one at the Imperial College where you are based.

Comment: I did search our online repository and couldn't find it.

Comment: Interlibrary loan?

Comment: I believe there is a facility to borrow books from the British library. I would be surprised if they didn't have it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Dear Martin, have you found it? I'm looking for it as well (please buzz me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether there is still a quest for McKean's original paper, but as a nice substitute, you can take a look at the very recent [review paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.14812.pdf) on "propagation of chaos". Theorem 5.1 there is a result due to McKean and the original proof of him is presented (starting from page 86).